# Get data from two last columns in table

Tags: vbscript, html-table

I'm trying to retrieve data from all the cells in the two last columns of a table with an unknown number of rows and columns. I have to do this by VBScript which I'm having difficulties with.

In the example below there are 2 rows with each 5 columns. However in my situation, the number of rows and columns varying.

I would like to get the data in the last two columns, being **Year 2015** and **Year 2016** in first row and **444** and **555** in second row etc. Since the rows and columns are varying I cannot find a fitting script for retrieving the data.

The data should be listed as variables, as I need to parse them into an input field.

```html
<table id="calculations_data" class="key_figures togglable">
    <tr>
      <th></th>
        <th scope="col">Year 2012</th>
        <th scope="col">Year 2013</th>
        <th scope="col">Year 2014</th>
        <th scope="col">Year 2015</th>
        <th scope="col">Year 2016</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
<tr id="turnover_data" class="data_row addaptive">
  <th class="title"><a href="#turnover_definition">Turnover</a></th>
    <td>111</td>
    <td>222</td>
    <td>333</td>
    <td>444</td>
    <td>555</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Furthermore the data is located in a website which I access by this script:

```vb
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "https://data.biq.dk/users/sign_in"
```

**Note:** The website above requires login which I manage via my script. The login details cannot be provided.

I have had success with the code below where the data is located in a  tag.

```vb
Data_CompanyName = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("h1")(0).innerText
Document.getElementByID("company_name").value = Data_CompanyName
```

Comment: Noone with a suggested solution to this problem?
I've been stuck since so I'm really hoping for help. Thanks! :-)

Comment: Let me know if the code posted works for you or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can extract the innerHTML of that table first and parse that innerHTML as we parse XML. Not sure if this is the best approach but it worked for me.

Try this code:

```
set objIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
objIE.visible = true
objIE.navigate "https://data.biq.dk/users/sign_in"     '<--make sure the correct path is entered here(the one which takes you to that page containing the table)
while objIE.readyState <>4 
    Wscript.sleep 1000
Wend
set objTable = objIE.document.getElementById("calculations_data")
strxml = objTable.innerhtml
set objXML = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
objXML.async=False
objXML.loadxml strxml
set objRowNodes = objXML.selectnodes("//tr")
for i=1 to objRowNodes.length-1
    tempArr = split(objRowNodes(i).text)
    msgbox "second last: "&tempArr(ubound(tempArr)-1)&vbcrlf&_   'Displays the 2nd last column data
           "last: "&tempArr(ubound(tempArr))                     'Displays the last column data
next
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Works perfect - thank you! Simple and elegant. I couple of tweaks and I can adapt it to my script. Thank you. Accepted as solution.